# Simple Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Among 60 automobile repair parts loaded on a truck in San Fransico , 45 are destined for seattle and 15 for vancouver. If two of the parts are unloaded in portland by mistake and the selection is random , what are the probabilities that 
one should have gone to seattle and one to Vancouver.

My attempt : So I first took out the probability of one part going to seattle and the other one going to vancouver which for me turned out to be $\frac{45}{60} * \frac{15}{59} $

But the correct answer that is listed is 1/243

What am I doing wrong , or is the listed answer wrong ?

Comment: I think you are right....but that answer is almost certainly wrong. How could the probability of having one part going to vancouver and one to seattle be so low?

Comment: Yes, the answer $1/243$ is wrong. Your answer is also not right, but "much closer."

Comment: Should I multiply my answer by 2 to account for both the cases (i.e. different orderings of the removal ? )  @Andre Nicolas

Comment: Yes, that's right. Imagine the two parts were unloaded one at a time. (That does not affect the probability.) Your calculation finds the probability that the first was destined for Seattle, and the second for Vancouver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listed answer is wrong, and so is your attempt, where you have forgotten to multiply by $2$ to take into account that $2$ sequences are possible for the choices.

Alternatively, $\dfrac{\binom{45}1\binom{15}1}{\binom{60}2} = \dfrac{45}{118}$

Comment: I had not multiplied by two , thinking that the removal of both the parts was simultaneous . Hence there is no need !

Comment: Drawing simultaneously amounts to drawing one by one w/o replace ment.It is a very common mistake to omit the multiplication factor in problems of drawing w/o replacement. When a specified sequence is not given, I greatly prefer using combinations.

Comment: As further insight, "drawing at once" implies that the sequence of draws is not specified, and that is why using combinations directly gives the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unloading one by one there are two mutually disjoint events that lead to the scenario: VS and SV. That gives a total probability of:$$\frac{15}{60}\frac{45}{59}+\frac{45}{60}\frac{15}{59}=\frac{45}{118}$$

There is no essential difference between unloading one by one and unloading both at the same moment.

---

Something to think about in order to train your intuition on this matter:

If e.g. there is exactly one red ball and exactly one blue ball and two balls are randomly picked at the same time then it is for certain that a red ball and a blue ball are picked. This is also the case if you pick the balls one by one.

The answer is $\frac12\frac11+\frac12\frac11=1$ and *not* $\frac12\frac11=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $_{15}C_2$ ways to pick two going to Vancouver, and $_{45}C_2$ ways to pick two going to Seattle.  What's left is one of each.  So the probability is

$$P = \frac{_{60}C_2 - _{45}C_2 - _{15}C_2}{_{60}C_2} = \frac{1770 - 990 - 105}{1770}=\frac{675}{1770} = \frac{45}{118}.$$